# Set different usercontrol in content template of expander

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]I want to embed different usercontrol inside the expander content template.

XAML:

```
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander  IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding}" Content="{Binding}">
                    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                    <Expander.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <usercontrol:UserListGrid   ></usercontrol:UserListGrid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Expander.ContentTemplate>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

instead of putting a single user control   inside the Expander.contenttemplate. My requirement is to show different user control inside the Expander.contenttemplate please suggest how i can achieve this.

I can achieve the same thing as like

```
 MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();
        for (var ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
        {
            Expander dynamicExpander = new Expander();
            dynamicExpander.Header = "New";

            dynamicExpander.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            dynamicExpander.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Lavender);

            dynamicExpander.IsExpanded = true;
            if (ii == 1 || ii==0)
            dynamicExpander.Content = GetGridContent("New");
            if (ii == 2 || ii == 4)
                dynamicExpander.Content = GetGridContent("New1");
            MyCollection.Add(dynamicExpander);
        }

    private object GetGridContent(string header)
   {
     if (header == "New")
     {
         return new UserListGrid();
     }
     else
     {
        return new UserControlInWork.InWorkGrid();

     }
  }
```

[image]
  I want to to achieve same thing with XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Grid` or any other control that is capable of containing child elements and define the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties:

```
<usercontrol:UserListGrid Grid.Row="0" />
<usercontrol:EquipemntListGrid  Grid.Row="1" />
```

Comment: Expander is already in listbox item template so number of row in list will generate different expander( as list row) and i want to embed different usercontrol in that row inside the expandercontent template.

Comment: @Gautam: did you set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: After set Grid.row basically it will come in same row as a template. my requirement is to set different user control in different row  .Which is expander as i already set expander in listbox item template.

Comment: Did you use values 0 and 1 for the user controls as in the sample? Else they will indeed be shown in the same line.

Comment: <usercontrol:UserListGrid Grid.Row="0"  ></UserListGrid>
                                    <usercontrol2:InWorkGrid Grid.Row="1"></usercontrol2:InWorkGrid> yes i use this .

Comment: I don't see an issue any more. Can you describe the problem better or add an image to your question to clarify?

Comment: I attached image there .I want to see different user control in differenet expander.

Comment: @Gautam: So why don't make two expanders? Or do you want ALL `UserListGrid` in one `Expander` and ALL `EquipmentListGrid` in another `Expander`?

Comment: Expander is dynamic .Number depends on the number of rows from DB. and Every expander will contain exactly one usercontrol basically grid.

Comment: @Gautam: And which user control does it have to show?

Comment: usercontrol is separate project and i want to import that user control in expander content which is in image is testusercontrol and second user control